# Getting Samba 4.1's "internal DNS" to update hostnames from dhcpd

Tags: dns, dhcp, hostname, active-directory, samba4

Samba 4 comes with its own "internal DNS" which can be used rather than BIND.  Since Samba 4's main new feature is AD replacement, I would figure that its DNS would function similarly to Windows Server's DNS, inasmuch as a client being given an address from a DHCP service on the same machine should notice the DNS of the client's hostname and new IP.

However, running Samba 4.1.3 with internal DNS, alongside `dhcpd`, on CentOS 6.4, I am experiencing the scenario that some DHCP clients do not get their hostnames registered.  It may just be ones connecting through a wireless router, I haven't checked all of them.  Such clients, I guess because they aren't reverse-DNS-able, and thus don't conform to the minimums needed for AD participation, cannot access the Samba fileshare (e.g. via `\\sambaserver` in Windows Explorer), but can only access our intranet server and the internet.

(Interestingly, some clients are pingable by their `client-hostname` fields as found in `/var/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases`, but return via a different name on the same domain than the one pinged. I.e. I `ping a` and it says `PING a.my.dom` followed by `64 bytes from a2.my.dom`. I'm not sure whether I consider this to be a problem, or if it's related to the above problem, but I include it in case it indicates some relevant information.)

How can I ensure that DHCP clients get their hostnames registered with DNS?
I've set `allow client-updates;` in `dhcpd.conf` and restarted the service.